# .contents of p element. Only goes one level down....need all contents. jquery

Tags: jquery

Have a problem. Taking this html:

```
 <p><span>js fiddle is a playground for
 web developers, a tool which may be
 used in many ways. One can use it as
 an online editor for snippets build
 from HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The
 code can then be shared with others,
 embedded on a blog, etc. Using this
 approach, JavaScript developers can
 very easily isolate bugs. We aim to
 support all actively developed
 frameworks - it helps with testing
 compatibility.</span></p>
```

I run this code:

```
var textNodes = $('p').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.length > 150;
}).parent().parent();

$(textNodes).css('border', '2px solid black');
```

the problem I have is that `contents()` only goes one level down...what I want is to test if a `p` element has greater than 150 `nodeType == 3` characters. If I do `contents().contents()....` this works

Comment: What's wrong with using `contents().contents()`? The `contents()` function is designed to get the immediate children of the selected element, so is working as intended in your example.

Comment: well i want to use it for cases where the text is not nested in <span> and where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```
var textNodes = $('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length > 150;
}).parent();

textNodes.css('border', '2px solid black');
```

Comment: What I want though, is to return only nodeType == 3....for that I need to use .contents()...is there any function which lets me get ALL the contents.

Comment: @Praneet: read the docs which I provided a link for. `$.text` returns just the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the `text` property of each `p` element. If it's greater than 150, change the CSS. See an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/ZA9fs/1/).

Comment: What I want though, is to return only nodeType == 3....for that I need to use .contents()...is there any function which lets me get ALL the contents

Comment: `text()`, as inferred from the name, does return the text nodes of the selected element. If you wanted to get HTML tags as well as text, you would use the `html()` function.